# Java - sending get to specific torrent from torcache throws IOException

Tags: java, get, httpurlconnection, ioexception

I have a piece of code in Java that creates a HTTPUrlConnection, sends GET and returns true if response code is 200 and false otherwise. The problem is that I'm trying to send GET to specific torcache "address", for example torcache.net/torrent/info-hash-here.torrent (info hash is a parameter in function). And I'm constantly getting IOException. Any ideas what can possibly go wrong - I ran out of them. 
Code here:

```
    public static boolean check(String infoHash)  {
    final String fileURL = "http://torcache.net/torrent/" + infoHash.toUpperCase() + ".torrent";
    if(connectAndGetResponseCode(fileURL) == 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

where method connectAndGetResponseCode is standard implementation of connecting given URL (no point of posting that). I checked and when I'm sending GET to simple torcache.net (or any other site) it returns 200. It's not the problem of infoHash either - I checked that too (I used those hashes "4FFA45CE7350E7AA19C90A432089662DCD2621D5" and "6F3DE950627A0BDB2023D34357DA766A6AE4C8AB" -> this one is invalid)
. Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: 
Connecting code:

```
 private static int connectAndGetResponseCode(String stringUrl) {
    int code = 0;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        code = connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong with getting a response from torcache.net");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
System.out.println(code);
    return code;
}
```

And stackTrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:778)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:775)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1325)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at WebChecker.connectAndGetResponseCode(WebChecker.java:14)
at WebChecker.check(WebChecker.java:26)
at WebChecker.main(WebChecker.java:37)
```

Edit #2 - wget results

I did it on both true and invalid hashes.

```
wget http://torcache.net/torrent/A633F505781CE03576E5B0F963793912D6927F12.torrent
--2015-11-15 19:50:30--  http://torcache.net/torrent/A633F505781CE03576E5B0F963793912D6927F12.torrent
```

Resolving torcache.net (torcache.net)... 94.242.255.194, 109.163.226.148, 95.215.61.199
Connecting to torcache.net (torcache.net)|94.242.255.194|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-11-15 19:50:33 ERROR 404: Not Found.

(fake, so it's 404 as expected)

```
wget http://torcache.net/torrent/4FFA45CE7350E7AA19C90A432089662DCD2621D5.torrent
```

--2015-11-15 19:51:15--  http://torcache.net/torrent/4FFA45CE7350E7AA19C90A432089662DCD2621D5.torrent
Resolving torcache.net (torcache.net)... 109.163.226.148, 95.215.61.199, 94.242.255.194
Connecting to torcache.net (torcache.net)|109.163.226.148|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 15466 (15K) [application/x-bittorrent]
Saving to: ‘4FFA45CE7350E7AA19C90A432089662DCD2621D5.torrent’
100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 15.466      1,22KB/s   in 14s
2015-11-15 19:51:29 (1,08 KB/s) - ‘4FFA45CE7350E7AA19C90A432089662DCD2621D5.torrent’ saved [15466/15466]

(valid hash - 200 as expected).

So I guess it works perfectly if someone wants to download a torrent file. But my point is only to check if it is possible to download it, not to do the action ;)

Comment: IOExceptions can mean any number of things - please post the stack trace.  Also, I can't find any docs on the connectAndGetResponseCode() method you refer to.  You might consider posting that as well.

Comment: Done - I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Wireshark:

1. Filter by 'host torcache.net'
2. Run wget (I assume it successfully loads target resource).
3. When wget is finished, then stop wireshark listening.
4. In wireshark right-click on any captured row/packet, and click follow tcp stream (see how it looks like: https://blogs.sans.org/appsecstreetfighter/files/2009/06/09-05-21-wireshark-follow.png)
5. Copy that http communication log (with methods, headers, body, response headers etc) into some sort of txt comparison software (meld, kdiff etc).

Repeat this procedure but instead of wget use your software.
Compare http communications and find if there are any differeences between wget and your software (e.g. in headers)

Comment: It's not possible from where I live, because my internet provider blocks any torrent attempts, so I'm using ssh connection and test it from console (javac and java). Hovewer it doesn't make a difference because I tested it without ssh in place where I can use torrents and the result was exactly the same. I will follow your advice tomorrow when I go to a torrent-possible location ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the future reference: problem is solved. If someone encountered similar one, the solution is:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

Torcache must "think" that get is being sent by browser ;)
With this it works perfectly. 
I guess the question should be marked as closed/solved.